# How to configure GlassFish v3.1 to use SSL?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, glassfish

We are looking for simple step-by-step manuals how to configure GlassFish v3.1 to use SSL. We are running few legacy application under GlassFish and we hope there is no need to change them: so that all SSL is just handled by GlassFish.

Answer (score -1):

I found the following on the web:
http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/getting-started-with-glassfish-v3-and-ssl/

I believe there is no need to modify your legacy application at all: GlassFish will pass unencrypted message to your app.